# Typescript error with width using stitches

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i want to ask about this typescript error on width

I created this component (progresbar) where i using [Stitches](https://stitches.dev/) for styling my component but typescript throwing me this kind of error even if I put type **ANY** there

```
import { FunctionComponent, ReactComponentElement } from 'react';

//style
import { styled } from 'stitches';
import type * as Stitches from '@stitches/react';

//components
import Typo from '@components/elements/Typo';

interface Props {
  readonly value: number;
  readonly max: number;
  readonly color?: string;

  //TODO type
  width?: any;
  readonly time?: string;
}

const ProgressBar: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  value,
  max,
  color = 'red',
  width,
  time = '24h'
}): ReactComponentElement<'div'> => {
  return (
    <Container color={color} width={width} className="ProgressBar">
      <progress value={value} max={max} />
      <Typo tag="span" size="t3" color="white" lineHeight={25} className="text">
        {time} ATH:{' '}
        {parseFloat(((value.toString() as any) / (max.toString() as any).toFixed(4)) as any) * 100}%
      </Typo>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled('div', {
  width: '70% !important',
  '& .text': { width: 165 },
  '& progress': {
    mr: 8,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '$gray3',
    border: '0.5px solid $gray3'
  },
  '& progress[value]': {
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: (value: Stitches.PropertyValue<'width'>) => ({
      width: value
    }),

    '&::-webkit-progress-bar': {
      height: 10,
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: '$tertiary'
    },
    '&::-webkit-progress-value': {
      height: 10,
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: (value: Stitches.PropertyValue<'backgroundColor'>) => ({
        backgroundColor: value
      })
    },
    '&::-moz-progress-bar': {
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: '$tertiary'
    }
  }
});

export default ProgressBar;
```

the error on width is here

```
(property) width: any
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }): ReactElement<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; color: string; width: any; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.
      Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }): ReactElement<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; color: string; width: any; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.
      Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css" | "as"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; }, "css"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }): ReactElement<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; color: string; width: any; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.
      Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, "css"> & TransformProps<...> & { ...; }'.ts(2769)
```

[image]

can someone pls explain why I got this kind of error pls thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hy there,

you can append to the end of your new styled component (`Container`), a new return type

```
type ContainerType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
    width?: string
}

type StyledContainerType = ComponentType<ContainerType>

const Container = styled('div', {
    width: '70% !important',
  '& .text': { width: 165 },
  '& progress': {
    mr: 8,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '$gray3',
    border: '0.5px solid $gray3'
  },
  '& progress[value]': {
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: (value: Stitches.PropertyValue<'width'>) => ({
      width: value
    }),

    '&::-webkit-progress-bar': {
      height: 10,
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: '$tertiary'
    },
    '&::-webkit-progress-value': {
      height: 10,
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: (value: Stitches.PropertyValue<'backgroundColor'>) => ({
        backgroundColor: value
      })
    },
    '&::-moz-progress-bar': {
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: '$tertiary'
    }
  }
})<{}, StyledContainerType>;
```

Comment: This works for me. However what does`{}` in `<{}, StyledContainerType>` signify? Anywhere I can read about this syntax?

Comment: They're [generics](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#generic-type-arguments-in-generic-tagged-templates), if you go to the [definition](https://github.com/stitchesjs/stitches/blob/canary/packages/react/types/stitches.d.ts#L47) of `styled` you'll see that the function accept some generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Prop `width` doesn't exist in `div`, you can use `style` prop to pass `width` and `color`:

```
 <Container style={{color, width}} className="ProgressBar">
      <progress value={value} max={max} />
      <Typo tag="span" size="t3" color="white" lineHeight={25} className="text">
        {time} ATH:{' '}
        {parseFloat(((value.toString() as any) / (max.toString() as any).toFixed(4)) as any) * 100}%
      </Typo>
 </Container>
```

Comment: thanks i know but if using just jsx its working because i pasing widht in stitches